# I Can't GA4 Total Revenue Calculate

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I can't track total revenue i added all custom js and parameters but i can see only conversion.When I checked value and price on reports all values are recieved. How can i fix this what am i missing

These are my custom js and tags options

[image: tag options]

[image: custom js]

Comment: have you called your purchase event from front-end? it needs to be triggered first.  Are price , value , and currency parameters customised parameters or they are google defaults, if they are customised you should create for every single customised parameter a customised dimension?